# How to convert String("ed") list to list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best method to convert a string like for example :

`"[[1, 't'], ['gg', 2]]"` which is a "quoted" list into:

```
[[1, 't'], ['gg', 2]]
```

To be more concrete, if I give as parameter to a python script a list it will be converted as a string automatically and I want to convert back this string into a list

So what i want is to "remove the quote" but i don't know what is the cleanest method to do it

Comment: check `ast.liter_eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
from ast import literal_eval
s = "[[1, 't'], ['gg', 2]]"
l = literal_eval(s)
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[[1, 't'], ['gg', 2]]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank a lot